# Statistics from a Minecraft PE world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing mostly ironman games (always a new world after death) on my Minecraft PE, and I would like to record some simple statistics about my games after I die. For example, world-days played, mobs killed, tools spent, etc.

Are there any external tools to extract these? Are they even recorded in the game?

Answer (score 2):

Stats are **not** in the latest version of Pocket Edition. **However**, there are mods for that. See this for more information on how to get mods:

Android:http://mcpedl.com/how-to-install-minecraft-pe-mods-for-android/
  iOS:http://mcpedl.com/how-to-install-minecraft-pe-mods-for-ios/